# Very undetailed normal map, blurry? High poly to low poly mesh help

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map

I am in the process of baking a normalmap from a high poly mesh down to a low poly mesh. I am getting a very blurry looking normalmap with bad results. Is there something I am doing wrong? The image for the normal is 1024^2, non alpha, 32bit checked. Using 1m ray distance. Any help on getting a detailed, accurate bake would be great! Thanks

[image: normal]
[image: uvs]
[image: high poly]

Comment: It looks like you have a rather large margin (default is 16px - too big in my opinion). Try reducing it to as low as 1 and see if that helps. You can change it in the output section of the bake settings.

Comment: I think that solved a lot of the problem on the normal map blurriness. It still is not entirely accurate, and there are artifacts.